# sjt.lmer displaying incorrect p-values

Tags: r, lme4

I've just noticed that sjt.lmer tables are displaying incorrect p-values, e.g., p-values that do not reflect the model summary. This appears to be a new-ish issue, as this worked fine last month?

Using the provided data and code in the package vignette

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
library(sjlabelled)
library(lme4)
library(sjstats)
```

## load sample data

```
data(efc)
```

## prepare grouping variables

```
efc$grp = as.factor(efc$e15relat)
levels(x = efc$grp) <- get_labels(efc$e15relat)
efc$care.level <- rec(efc$n4pstu, rec = "0=0;1=1;2=2;3:4=4",
```

val.labels = c("none", "I", "II", "III"))

## data frame for fitted model

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  neg_c_7 = efc$neg_c_7,
  sex = to_factor(efc$c161sex),
  c12hour = efc$c12hour,
  barthel = efc$barthtot,
  education = to_factor(efc$c172code),
  grp = efc$grp,
  carelevel = to_factor(efc$care.level)
)
```

## fit sample models

```
fit1 <- lmer(neg_c_7 ~ sex + c12hour + barthel + (1 | grp), data = mydf)
summary(fit1)
p_value(fit1, p.kr =TRUE)
```

## model summary

[image: model summary]

## p_value summary

[image: p_value summary]

## sjt.lmer output does not show these p-values??

[image: sjt.lmer summary]

Comment: Can you please post summary as text, not images?

Comment: possible problem with contrasts being set in one place and overlooked somewhere else?  What is `options("contrasts")`,  and what happens if you reset it to the default `options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the first summary comes from a model fitted with *lmerTest*, which computes p-values with df based on Satterthwaite approximation (see first line in output).

`p_value()`, however, with `p.kr = TRUE`, uses the Kenward-Roger approximation from package *pbkrtest*, which is a bit more conservative.

Your output from `sjt.lmer()` seems to be messed up somehow, and I can't reproduce it with your example. My output looks ok:

[image]

Comment: Thanks all - this appears to be an issue with package conflicts -- reinstalling the sj packages (and removing lmertest) and restarting R several times seems to have cleared the issue. Many thanks - your answers pointed me in the 'it's a software thing' direction. Cheers, Emily